# What is "application/x-amz-json" and how is it different from "application/json"?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've run into "application/x-amz-json-1.1" in making requests to AWS resources. Most recently, it became a problem that an API Gateway I was communicating with didn't like handling it (for whatever reason). This got me wondering what the benefit to using application/x-amz-json-1.1 instead of application/json for my requests is. And to my disappointment, AWS doesn't seem to have any documentation on this odd content type.

**So I turn to SO: what is "application/x-amz-json" and how is it different from "application/json"?**

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/API_Reference.html it seems that 'application/x-amz-json-1.1' -----> Specifies that the request content is JSON. Also specifies the JSON version. That's all the different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon does not specifically document what `application/x-amz-json` Content-Type is for, however there are protocol documentations on [Smithy](https://awslabs.github.io/smithy/) (an open source *language for defining services and SDKs* published by AWS):

- [AWS JSON 1.1 protocol](https://awslabs.github.io/smithy/1.0/spec/aws/aws-json-1_1-protocol.html)
- [AWS JSON 1.0 protocol](https://awslabs.github.io/smithy/1.0/spec/aws/aws-json-1_0-protocol.html)

Considering the question relates to the difference when used as `Content-Type`<sup>1</sup> header to make requests, I think we can tell the difference is:

- `application/json` is to request/receive JSON data without anything more specific
- `application/x-amz-json-1.1` (or other version) is also to request/receive JSON data *and* expect additional behaviors described in the docs above. (i.e. tell the server/client this is JSON plus additional elements)

I think `application/x-amz-json` can be thought as a sort of extension or a more specific way of doing `application/json` requests.

> it became a problem that an API Gateway I was communicating with didn't like handling it (for whatever reason)

In the specific case of making PATCH, PUT and POST requests to AWS  Amazon API Gateway, specifying `Content-Type` header `application/x-amz-json-1.1` or other version seems to be required. As per [related docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/):

> Content-Type (Conditional)
>
> Specifies JSON and the version, for example, Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0.
>
> Condition: **Required for PATCH, PUT and POST requests.**

Maybe the server understands `application/json` as basic JSON but requires `application/x-amz-json-1.1` to perform specific requests.

---

<sup>1</sup> `Content-Tye` header being used to tell the server/client how to process our request

Comment: Interestingly there are 2 aws api gws my project calls, one of them accepts `application/x-amz-json-1.0` (I didn't try others), while another **requires** `application/json` and fails with `x-amz...` 

Comment: "required for POST" bit is so easy to misread... I though that Pierre meant that `x-amz...` is required when issuing POST requests against the API GW; while in fact (?) it's only that the `Content-Type` request header field is required for requests that have a body (PATCH/PUT/POST), while the value of the field is not mandated.

Comment: You're not wrong, I reformulated to clarify this.